# Как в Delphi XE подключиться к базам 1С 8.2?

Tags: 1с, delphi, база-данных

ODBC или ещё как? Может, кто даст хотя бы ссылку, где подробно расписан весь процесс.

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](http://doc-prg.narod.ru/index_1cv8.htm) рассмотрена работа с 8кой из Delphi во всех подробностях.